# syntax error when creating FK and am I adding a picture from a user input in sql server correctly or there is another way

Tags: mysql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE CHATTING(

                    CHATID      DECIMAL(10) IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                    TEXTRCVD    VARCHAR(154) NOT NULL,
                    PARTYDATE   VARCHAR(154) NOT NULL /*REFERENCES CHATTING (CHATID)*/,
                    )

CREATE TABLE PICS(

                    PICID           DECIMAL(10) IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                    PIC             VARBINARY(MAX),
                    PIC_DATETIME    VARCHAR(154) NOT NULL /*REFERENCES PICS (PICID)*/,
                    )   

/*CREATING PK AND FK*/

ALTER Table CHATTING ADD 

                    FOREIGN KEY (PARTYDATE) REFERENCES (CHATID)

ALTER TABLE PICS ADD

                    FOREIGN KEY (PIC_DATETIME) REFERENCES (PICID)


INSERT INTO CHATTING (CHATID, TEXTRCVD, PARTYDATE)

SELECT 1, 'TEST', BulckColumn

                            from OPENROWSET( BULK /*'SERVER'S EXTENSTION TO TAKE DATE FROM OR TO CONNECT WITH */, SINGLE_BLOB) AS IMAGE

/*TO SEARCH FOR TEXT OR PICTURES*/

SELECT * FROM CHATTING 

                      WHERE @USERSTART=CHATID;

SELECT * FROM PICS

                    WHERE @USERSTART=PICID;
```

Comment: What statement causes the error, and what error are you getting?

Comment: when creating foreign key and this is the error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near '('.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because primary and foreign key should be same data type